# What is the best way for delete a row in CursorAdapter?

Tags: android, performance

What is the best way for delete a row in CursorAdapter ?
I use ViewHolder pattern.

Comment: It really depends where your data comes from and if you want to delete it from the UI only or delete it forever from a database. Answer those question it'll help SO users figure out your problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to simply delete the row from the database, either from within your ContentProvider or using a raw query. Once you have performed the delete, all you have to do is call the changeCursor(Cursor cursor) result on the CursorAdapter. This will automatically update the views (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#changeCursor(android.database.Cursor)).

As a priciple, you should be doing the delete and the cursor update in a background thread.

Comment: Thanks you. There is no better way instead of change cursor ? change cursor have a little jump when fast scroll (i using animation)

Comment: Unfortunately no.. there is an alternate method swapCursor(Cursor cursor) which simply returns the old cursor but performance wise, I think they will both be the same. If you will be fast scrolling as you do the delete, I am sure there will be an associated performance cost. An option would be to temporarily disable the fast scroll while doing the delete - like show a progress bar (or circle) during the delete which will pause the activity until the delete is complete

Comment: Progress is a good idea. Thanks to you. Good things i learned from you.

Comment: Well don't use raw query for delete operations instead use execSql . After deletion you can change cursor and call notifydatasetchanged().